# What are expansion joint requirements for magnesium oxide wallboards?

Tags: drywall, installation

I was asked to get some information concerning installing [magnesium oxide wallboards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnesium_oxide_wallboard). It's a material I just got to know and never worked with, so I want to learn what are requirements for installing these, specifically:

1. Do I need to make special expansion joints, and - if so - what material is best for to fill the gap?
2. If expansion joints are not needed - if I fix several of these with some kind of glue (or other compund) so they will form a larger surface - do I need to make some expansion joints then?

My question is about indoor-related works as these wallboards are seens as a substitute to [drywall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drywall). Any related info (e.g. install manuals) greatly appreciated.

I need answers from hands-on experienced DIY-ers best. These wallboards aren't popular where I live, so I try my luck here, in DIY SE :)

Comment: I have only used for a tile backer on walls I usually fill the gap with morter. there is a fiberglass mesh/ tape that could be used in the edge depression and filled like sheetrock but I have no idea how you could sand any high spots, probably best used with a heavy texture or "stomp" pattern

Comment: @Ed Beal So it just looks like a drywall-way. I was guessing that it can be done like that. Thx for Your input.

Comment: I'd never heard of this product.  In looking it up, I found [this article](http://www.concretecottage.com/Magnesium-oxide-boards.htm) that might be informative for any other MgO noobs.

Answer (score 1):

The best place to go for this sort of question is the manufacturer.  I deal with National Gypsum, USG, and others ALL THE TIME for questions like this.  Typically, the manufacturers web site will have all the design criteria you could ever want - if they don't, I would look for another manufacturer who took the time to make that information available.  These guys are generally very willing to help as a seccusful installation always looks good for them.  Give them a call.